# setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true) not showing progress bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I already have the

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
```

and the

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
if (isOnline()) {
    retrieveProfile();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, getString(R.string.internet_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

This code was already working, but somehow the progress bar doesn't show anymore.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Should `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` be inside the `else` section?

Comment: I fixed it already. I placed the `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` inside both of the if and else statements. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't show the bar, it just makes it show an indeterminate bar rather than a determinate bar.  You still need to call  setProgressBarVisibility(true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)
```

to get backward compatibility.

Comment: This is now deprecated. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(boolean)